# custom_marker_icon >=0.2.0, version solving failed

Tags: android, flutter, dart

my pubspec.yaml file

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  custom_info_window: ^1.0.1
  custom_marker_icon: ^0.2.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^1.1.1
```

when run

```
dart pub upgrade --major-versions
```

> Error:

Because every version of custom_marker_icon depends on google_maps_flutter ^1.1.1 and custom_info_window >=1.0.0 depends on google_maps_flutter ^2.0.2, custom_marker_icon is incompatible with custom_info_window >=1.0.0.
So, because flutter_appgooglemap depends on both custom_info_window >=1.0.1 and custom_marker_icon >=0.2.0, version solving failed.

Comment: try to add another version

Comment: for example, give me

Comment: Try to upgrade the google maps plugin to the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes to your `pubspec.yaml` file

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  custom_marker_icon: ^0.2.0
  custom_info_window: ^1.0.1

dependency_overrides:
  google_maps_flutter: ^1.1.1
```